# GitHub commits acting rather strangely

Tags: github, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I'm relatively new to Git and all of this but as of recently my commits gave gone funky. You might be asking yourself what I'm talking about. Well...

[image: commit]

All of my new commits look like this. It appears as though a "non GitHub" person has commited the message.
All I can do is add myself as a co-author. It looks like this.

[image: Image 2]

I've tried reinstalling Git, JetBrains IDEs. No luck. Can anyone please help me.   And yes. I'm sort of a newbie. Don't judge me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you have your global configuration correctly set when making commits:

```
git config --global user.name misobarisic
git config --global user.email <github_email>
```

That is: use your GitHub username account ([`github.com/misobarisic`](https://github.com/misobarisic)) *and* GitHub user email.

Then create a new commit and push it, to check the problem is no longer there.

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem is no more!